# Face Geometry with Three.js and TensorFlow.js?

Tags: javascript, html, algorithm, tensorflow, three.js

I'm having a problem designing a project similar as polycam or avaturn.me? I have a problem using TensorFlow.js and three.js to Face Geometry with Three.js and TensorFlow.js and preview it in 3d scenes of three.js. so what how can fix that? Three.js and TensorFlow.js to create face geometry from a camera feed

TensorFlow.js
three.js

here you find html file :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Face Geometry with Three.js and TensorFlow.js</title>
  <style>
    body {
      margin: 0;
      overflow: hidden;
    }
    canvas {
      display: block;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <button id="cameraButton">Open Camera</button>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/three@0.132.2/build/three.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@tensorflow/tfjs@3.11.0"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@tensorflow-models/face-landmarks-detection@0.2.4/dist/face-landmarks-detection.js"></script>

  <script>
    // Initialize Three.js scene
    const scene = new THREE.Scene();
    const camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(75, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 0.1, 1000);
    const renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
    renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
    document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

    // Create a video element to display the camera feed
    const video = document.createElement('video');
    video.width = window.innerWidth;
    video.height = window.innerHeight;
    document.body.appendChild(video);

    // Load face detection model from TensorFlow.js
    let modelPromise = null;
    async function loadModel() {
      modelPromise = tf.loadGraphModel('https://tfhub.dev/mediapipe/tfjs-model/face_landmark/3/default/1', { fromTFHub: true });
      await modelPromise;
    }

    // Perform face detection on each frame
    async function detectFaces() {
      const predictions = await modelPromise.executeAsync(tf.browser.fromPixels(video));
      const faces = predictions[0];

      // Clear previous face meshes from the scene
      scene.children.forEach(child => {
        if (child.userData.type === 'faceMesh') {
          scene.remove(child);
        }
      });

      // Create face geometry for each detected face
      for (const face of faces) {
        const faceGeometry = new THREE.BufferGeometry();
        const positions = new Float32Array(face.mesh.shape[0] * face.mesh.shape[1] * 3);

        // Flatten the face mesh positions array
        for (let i = 0; i < face.mesh.shape[0]; i++) {
          for (let j = 0; j < face.mesh.shape[1]; j++) {
            positions[i * face.mesh.shape[1] * 3 + j * 3] = face.mesh[i][j][0];
            positions[i * face.mesh.shape[1] * 3 + j * 3 + 1] = face.mesh[i][j][1];
            positions[i * face.mesh.shape[1] * 3 + j * 3 + 2] = face.mesh[i][j][2];
          }
        }

        faceGeometry.setAttribute('position', new THREE.BufferAttribute(positions, 3));

        const faceMaterial = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({ color: 0xff0000 });
        const faceMesh = new THREE.Mesh(faceGeometry, faceMaterial);
        faceMesh.userData.type = 'faceMesh';
        scene.add(faceMesh);
      }

      predictions[0].dispose();
    }

    // Start the video stream from the camera
    async function startCamera() {
      try {
        const stream = await navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({ video: true });
        video.srcObject = stream;
        video.onloadedmetadata = () => {
          video.play();
          animate();
        };
      } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error accessing the camera:', error);
      }
    }

    // Set up animation loop
    function animate() {
      requestAnimationFrame(animate);
      detectFaces();
      renderer.render(scene, camera);
    }

    // Add event listener to the camera button
    const cameraButton = document.getElementById('cameraButton');
    cameraButton.addEventListener('click', startCamera);

    // Start the web project
    async function start() {
      await loadModel();
    }

    start();
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```